# In multiple locks when first thread has locked on to first task, how to make second thread to not sit idle and instead lock on to next task?

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

Processor class -

```
public class Processor extends Thread {
    private static final Object lock1 = new Object();
    private static final Object lock2 = new Object();

    private void doJob1() {
        synchronized (lock1) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " doing job1");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed job1");
        }
    }

    private void doJob2() {
        synchronized (lock2) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " doing job2");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed job2");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        doJob1();
        doJob2();
    }
}
```

Main method -

```
    final Processor processor1 = new Processor();
    final Processor processor2 = new Processor();

    processor1.start();
    processor2.start();
```

Here on first run either Thread-0 or Thread-1 takes a lock of job1() and the other sits idle for 5 seconds.

After the first thread releases the lock on job1() and locks job2(), the second thread takes a lock on job1().

I want that the second thread should not sit idle and since job1() is locked by first thread, it should instead lock job2() and then lock job1().

How to do so?

Note: This is the basic blue print. In reality I want my code to work even if there are a 100 tasks and 5 threads.

Comment: You really should change your design. A thread should not hold a lock while it's doing a job, only while it's actually manipulating shared state. If you are worried about how long a thread might wait trying to acquire a lock, the problem is some other thread holding the lock for too long. Locks generally just shouldn't be used that way.

Comment: To use a bit of an analogy, say two people share a car. If you place the lock on the car, then I can't even check to see if the car is available without waiting for the other person to bring the car back. That's not a good design. The lock should, instead, protect the hangar we place the keys on when we're not using the car. Acquire the lock, check if the keys are there (maybe taking them if they are), release the lock. Acquire the lock, put the keys back, release the lock. The shared state is who has the keys, not the position of the car!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more complicated example with an object for the job and the condition variable that indicates whether the job has been performed, and examples of how wrappers can adapt a `ReentrantLock` to a try-with-resources statement.

```
/**
 * A Job represents a unit of work that needs to be performed once and
 * depends upon a lock which it must hold while the work is performed.
 */
public class Job {
    private final Runnable job;
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private boolean hasRun;

    public Job(Runnable job, ReentrantLock lock) {
        this.job = Objects.requireNonNull(job);
        this.lock = Objects.requireNonNull(lock);
        this.hasRun = false;
    }

    /**
     * @returns true if the job has already been run
     */
    public boolean hasRun() {
        return hasRun;
    }

    // this is just to make the test in Processor more readable
    public boolean hasNotRun() {
        return !hasRun;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to perform the job, returning immediately if the job has
     * already been performed or the lock cannot be obtained.
     *
     * @returns true if the job was performed on this invocation
     */
    public boolean tryPerform() {
        if (hasRun) {
            return false;
        }
        try (TryLocker locker = new TryLocker(lock)) {
            if (locker.isLocked()) {
                job.run();
                hasRun = true;
            }
        }
        return hasRun;
    }
}

/**
 * A Locker is an AutoCloseable wrapper around a ReentrantLock.
 */
public class Locker implements AutoCloseable {
    private final ReentrantLock lock;

    public Locker(final ReentrantLock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
        lock.lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

/**
 * A TryLocker is an AutoCloseable wrapper around a ReentrantLock that calls
 * its tryLock() method and provides a way to test whether than succeeded.
 */
public class TryLocker implements AutoCloseable {
    private final ReentrantLock lock;

    public TryLocker(final ReentrantLock lock) {
        this.lock = lock.tryLock() ?  lock : null;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return lock != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (isLocked()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A modified version of the Processor class from the question.
 */
public class Processor extends Thread {
    private static final ReentrantLock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final ReentrantLock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

    private void snooze(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private void doJob1() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " doing job1");
        snooze(5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed job1");
    }

    private void doJob2() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " doing job2");
        snooze(5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed job2");
    }

    public void run() {
        Job job1 = new Job(() -> doJob1(), lock1);
        Job job2 = new Job(() -> doJob2(), lock2);

        List<Job> jobs = List.of(job1, job2);

        while (jobs.stream().anyMatch(Job::hasNotRun)) {
            jobs.forEach(Job::tryPerform);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Processor processor1 = new Processor();
        final Processor processor2 = new Processor();

        processor1.start();
        processor2.start();
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- The `run()` method in `Processor` now generalizes to a list of *n* jobs. While any of the jobs have not been performed, it will try to perform them, completing after all jobs are done.
- The `TryLocker` class is `AutoCloseable`, so locking and unlocking in `Job` can be done by creating an instance of it in a **try-with-resources** statement.
- The `Locker` class is unused here but demonstrates how the same thing could be done for a blocking `lock()` call instead of a `tryLock()` call.
- `TryLocker` could also take a time period and call the overload of `tryLock` that waits for up to an amount of time before giving up, if desired; that modification is left as an exercise for the reader.
- The `hasNotRun()` method of `Job` is just there to make `anyMatch(Job::hasNotRun)` a little more readable in the `run()` method of `Processor`; it probably isn't pulling its weight, and could be dispensed with.
- The locker classes don't check that the lock passed in is not null using `Objects.requireNonNull`; they use it right away by calling a method on it, so if it's null they will still throw an NPE, but putting an explicit requireNonNull might make them clearer.
- The locker classes don't bother to check if they've already unlocked the `ReentrantLock` before calling `unlock()` to make them idempotent; they will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` in that case. In the past I wrote a variation on this with a flag variable to avoid this, but since the intention is to use them in a **try-with-resources** statement, which will only call the `close()` method once, I think it's better to let them blow up if someone manually calls the close method.

Comment: Job::tryPerform is showing unhandled exception

Comment: I had to catch exception there

Comment: @PayelSenapati It doesn't for me. On which line? With what version of Java?

Comment: In class Processor, within while block Job:tryPerform which maps to Job class tryPerform() where I have to put a try /catch

Comment: Java version - 11.0.9 Open JDK for Linux

Comment: That's strange, because Job::tryPerform isn't declared as throwing any exceptions. Do you still have doJob1() and doJob2() calling Thread.sleep() directly? I changed those, since the run() method of a Runnable can't throw an exception.

Comment: Maybe something specific to Open JDK and not Oracle JDK?

Comment: Very strange. I don't know why that would be. It didn't require that for any of a number of versions of the JDK I tried.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, you are looking for a way to *"acquire a lock if possible and do something else if it's not free"*.

You can do it using the [`ReentrantLock#tryLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()).

The method:

> Acquires the lock only if it is not held by another thread at the time of invocation.

And it returns:

> `true` if the lock was free and was acquired by the current thread, or the lock was already held by the current thread; and `false` otherwise

Here is a modified version of code from the question:

- if a lock for first task is free a thread will run the first job
- otherwise it will run it after the second one

`Processor.java`:

```java
public class Processor extends Thread {
    private static final Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

    @SneakyThrows
    private void doJob1() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " doing job1");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed job1");
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void doJob2() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " doing job2");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed job2");
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean executedFirst = false;
        if (lock1.tryLock()) {
            try {
                doJob1();
                executedFirst = true;
            } finally {
                lock1.unlock();
            }
        }
        try {
            lock2.lock();
            doJob2();
        } finally {
            lock2.unlock();
        }

        if (!executedFirst) {
            try {
                lock1.lock();
                doJob1();
            } finally {
                lock1.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Processor().start();
        new Processor().start();
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Thread-1 doing job2
Thread-0 doing job1
Thread-0 completed job1
Thread-1 completed job2
Thread-1 doing job1
Thread-0 doing job2
Thread-1 completed job1
Thread-0 completed job2
```

Note that, the `lock`/`tryLock` and `unlock` invocations are surrounded into `try`/`finally`

---

Going into baskets and balls:

`Color.java`:

```java
public enum Color {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE;

    public static Color fromOrdinal(int i) {
        for (Color value : values()) {
            if (value.ordinal() == i) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown ordinal = " + i);
    }
}
```

`Basket.java`:

```java
@Data(staticConstructor = "of")
public class Basket {
    private final Color color;
    // balls that this basket has
    private final List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
}
```

`Ball.java`

```java
@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
public class Ball {
    Color color;
}
```

`Boy.java`

- Each boy picks a ball (`queue.poll()`)
- Runs to basket (`baskets.get(color)` with the same color)
- And depending on behavior when a basket is occupied he:

  - throws ball away and tries again (option `a` in code)
  - waits until the basket is freed (option `b`)
- Note that with option `a` it is possible for some `boy` to terminate in between when the other one throws away a `ball` and nobody has picked it up yet (anyway, someone will pick it up and put into the basket)

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Boy implements Runnable {
    private final Map<Color, Basket> baskets;
    private final Queue<Ball> balls;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Ball ball;
        while ((ball = balls.poll()) != null) {
            Color color = ball.getColor();
            Basket basket = baskets.get(color);
            // a
            if (basket.getLock().tryLock()) {
                try {
                    basket.getBalls().add(ball);
                } finally {
                    basket.getLock().unlock();
                }
            } else {
                balls.offer(ball);
            }

            // b
            /*
            try {
                basket.getLock().lock();
                basket.getBalls().add(ball);
            } finally {
                basket.getLock().unlock();
            }
             */
        }
    }
}
```

and finally `main`:

```java
Queue<Ball> balls = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 3)
        .mapToObj(Color::fromOrdinal)
        .map(Ball::of)
        .limit(1000)
        .forEach(balls::add);
Map<Color, Basket> baskets = Map.of(
        Color.RED, Basket.of(Color.RED),
        Color.GREEN, Basket.of(Color.GREEN),
        Color.BLUE, Basket.of(Color.BLUE)
);
List<Thread> threads = IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .mapToObj(ignore -> new Boy(baskets, balls))
        .map(Thread::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
threads.forEach(Thread::start);
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}

baskets.forEach((color, basket) -> System.out.println("There are "
        + basket.getBalls().size() + " ball(-s) in " + color + " basket"));
```

Example of output:

```
There are 331 ball(-s) in GREEN basket
There are 330 ball(-s) in BLUE basket
There are 339 ball(-s) in RED basket
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :) I would take this a step further by wrapping the job and its condition variable in an object and having a helper method that tries to lock, executes, and sets the flag, and then you could loop over them until they're all done. I would also create an Autocloseable wrapper that calls unlock so that I could use a try-with-resources, but that's obviously all beyond the scope of this question and answer.

Comment: I also thought about a more sophisticated approach first, but it looked to me that OP was simply looking for `tryLock` :)

Comment: @DavidConrad please add an answer as well

Comment: @DenisZavedeev what is @SneakyThrows?

Comment: @PayelSenapati, it's from [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) - some magic that allows you to not declare checked exceptions to be thrown

Comment: @DenisZavedeev it works fine here, but suppose the work is far more complex, say 10 jobs and 3 threads, this approach will make a huge and dirty code, any better approach?

Comment: This depends on the problem itself: do you want **all** of three `thread`s to execute **each of** ten tasks with least blocking of threads possible without any guaranteed order of execution of tasks? Or do you want something else?

Comment: I want a randomness, suppose there are 1000 balls of read, green, blue and three baskets of red, green, blue. The balls are needed to be put in baskets of same color. I have 10 ball boys and each basket can be occupied by only 1 ball boy at a time. Also a ball boy will not go to basket 2 if basket 1 is occupied as a rule, it will go to either basket 2 or 3, ie. any basket that is free.

Comment: What should other boys do? Do boys take a basket and never release them, or they take a ball, take matching basket and put the ball into it? And if the basket is not free they throw the ball away? I think the key here either way would be encapsulating jobs into some `Runnable` and careful mapping from a `Basket` to corresponding `lock`

Comment: @PayelSenapati I have added an answer with the ideas I mentioned above worked out in detail.

Comment: @DenisZavedeev Each boy picks up any ball at random and runs at basket, the 3 boys who manages to occupy basket, they occupy them at any order, not necessarily 1, 2 and 3, while the other boys wait till any basket gets free. Most importantly there is no hard and fast basket 1, 2, 3 - total randomness, which ever basket a boy is able to occupy.

Comment: @PayelSenapati I've added sample code that tries to emulate boys and baskets. Hope this helps

Comment: @DenisZavedeev I regret I cannot upvote this a second time for the baskets and balls answer. Cheers.